# Azure Pipeline Xcode build not picking the Entitlements files

Tags: azure-devops, xcode12, azure-deployment

Azure iOS build pipeline is not picking Entitlements files and due to that Apply Pay configuration is missing app is failing to provide Apple pay method. can anyone help is there any option there to set picking the entitlements in Azure Pipeline?

Comment: Did you just use the  **Publish to app store task**?  Could you share related settings here? Besides, also share any related log part here for further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem with other entitlements.  What eventually got it for me was making sure the Xcode build task had manual signing selected.  As long as you've installed your certificate and provisioning profile, you can set the following on the Xcode build Signing & provisioning section:

Signing Style: `Manual signing`

Signing Identity: `$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)`

Provisioning profile UUID: `$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)`